# How to correct this unsequenced modification?

Tags: c++, ios

I am using some open source code and I found this occurrence of un-sequenced modification.

Following is the code:

```
...
float32x4_t *_M, *_S, _norm;
int n4 = ...;
...
for(; i<n4; i++)
    *_M++ = MUL(*_M, RCP(ADD(*_S++, _norm)));
...
```

How do I sequence this modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that experienced with this, but

```
for(; i<n4; i++) {
    *_M = MUL(*_M, RCP(ADD(*_S, _norm)));
    M++;
    S++;
}
```

should be equivalent.

Comment: Compiling this in Xcode results in 'Expression result unused'.

Comment: Get rid of the `*` on the last two lines. You just want to increment the pointers, not dereference them and discard the result.